# compile returns error with theme extension

Tags: magento2

When I run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I get an error with one of my theme's extensions:

> Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2' not found in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/MageBig/SocialLogin/Model/Providers/Amazon.php
>   on line 26

Comment: past contend of file Amazon.php from line 20 to 30

Comment: I got the same error while trying to run the 'magento setup:di:compile' command 'Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/MageBig/SocialLogin/Model/Providers/Amazon.php on line 26' After Reinstalling Hybrid Auth https://doc.magebig.com/martfury/extensions/#social-login I then got the error 'Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/MageBig/SocialLogin/Model/Providers/Amazon.php on line 30' What did I do wrong. Any Ideas?
Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install Hybrid Auth
https://doc.magebig.com/martfury/extensions/#social-login

After that, I was able to compile without errors.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you just copy paste this social login module in your project

if you see it's composer.json file here https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-social-login/blob/master/composer.json

you will get an idea there is the dependency on `"hybridauth/hybridauth": "^2.11.0"`, that's why you get an error

what you should do now is try to run below commands

> composer require mageplaza/magento-2-social-login
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-social-login this line will install all its dependency modules
```

For more details follow it's setup guide https://www.mageplaza.com/install-magento-2-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Install the dependency, after that you will able to compile without errors.

```
composer require hybridauth/hybridauth: ^2.11.0
```